# Formatting choice list options in entity form type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-sonata

i'm using Entity form type, choice based, in order to provide a choice list inside a Sonata Admin form. What i would like is to use a child property to display the collection of elements inside the choice list.

Does any one knows how to provide the label to be shown inside the chocie list or how to give format to the choice list array?

```
    $formMapper->add( 'frArea', 'entity', array(
        'class'             => 'myVendor\myBundleBundle\View\myEntity',
        //When using a child property here, choice list gets corrupted/bad formatted
        //'property'            => 'child.property',
        'property'          => 'property',
        'em'                => 'formacions',
        'query_builder'     =>  function( EntityRepository $er )
                                {
                                    return $er->createQueryBuilder( 'qb' )
                                              ->add( 'select', 'm' )
                                              ->add( 'from', 'myVendor\myBundleBundle\View\myEntity m' );
                                              //->leftJoin('a.idiomes', 'ai');
                                },
        'required'          => false, 
        'label'             => ucfirst( $this->trans( 'my_label', array(), $this->translationDomain, $this->langCode ) )
    ) );
```

When using property option in the following way `'property' => 'child.property'` i get the following error:

```
Neither property "nom" nor method "getProperty()" nor method "isProperty()" exists in class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the role of the parameter `property` ! No need to indicate to Symfony which field is option's value, it takes the ID column, so `property` is used for display ;)

Comment: Thx, but as you've seen in the post i have issues when property alue is a child entity proprty. I've editted the post to show the error i get when doing that.

Comment: Have you tried to write a public accessor from MyEntity m to related child entity ?

Comment: No, will try and post here. Thx!

Comment: Not the solution i was looking for, but at least got what i wanted.Thx!